# Need help on model automorphism

Tags: model-theory

Here is another problem in "Model Theory" (Chang-Keisler 2012) that I need help.

> Exercise $1.3.22$. Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a countable model for a
> countable language. Prove that if the simple expansion $(\mathfrak{A},$
> $b)$ has more than one automorphism for each finite sequence $b$ of
> elements of $A$, then $\mathfrak{A}$ has $2^{\omega}$ automorphisms.

I know how to prove automorphism by back and forth method. But I am not sure how to prove the number of automorphisms for a model.

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Comment: Just ignore the downvoted: they provide as much information as white noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is the following (I come short of proving that the construction works as intended).

Construct a function $b:2^{<\omega}\to A$ such that

0. $b(\alpha^\frown0)\neq b(\alpha^\frown1)$ for all $\alpha\in2^{<\omega}$;
1. every infinite branch enumerates $A$, i.e. $\{b(\alpha{\restriction} n) : n\in\omega\}$ is an enumeration of $A$ for all $\alpha\in2^{\omega}$;
2. there is an automorphism $f_{\alpha,\beta}: b(\alpha{\restriction} i)\mapsto b(\beta{\restriction} i)$ for every $n$, every $\alpha,\beta\in2^{n}$ and $i<n$.

Assume inductively that $b(\alpha)$ is defined for all $\alpha\in2^{<m}$ and that (2) holds for $n<m$.

Pick any $\gamma\in2^{m-1}$. By assumption, there are two distinct $b(\gamma^\frown0), b(\gamma^\frown 1)$ that are conjugate over $\{b(\gamma{\restriction}i)\, :\, i<n\}$.

Now for every $\alpha\in2^{m-1}$ let $f_{\gamma,\alpha}$ be the automorphism obtained from (2). Define

$\quad b(\alpha^\frown0)=f_{\gamma,\alpha}\big(b(\gamma^\frown0)\big)$ and

$\quad b(\alpha^\frown1)=f_{\gamma,\alpha}\big(b((\gamma^\frown1)\big)$.

Comment: $b$ is a funtion that takes as inputs finite sequences of 0s and 1s. I have called it a tree, maybe improperly. $\alpha^\frown0$ denotes the concatenation of $\alpha$ and 0